Use dynamic Column Name while adding custom column in Power Query
Is there a way to write a query for Custom Column in Power BI to use value from one column as column name?
Something like:
T1 = [Position] 
Table.AddColumn(#"Added custom 3", "Total", each [T1])

I have an issue with combining Excel files in Power BI which have different format:


I want to

Load all files together (there will multiple files from multiple years)
Get the total column per file (Broken by Year would be a bonus)

I was able to transform the data to get column with total per file:

Can I write a Custom Query which will pick up the value from the helper table and use that value as column name?

Yes, you can.  Probably by using the Table.Pivot function.

Paste your sample data as text and mark your old questions as solved please.

In code you are trying you can use something like:
T1 = [Position] 
Table.AddColumn(#"Added custom 3", "Total", each Record.Value(_, T1))

But I recommend to proccess your original files some thing like:

Open file
Skip all rows until value in the second column = "Year"
Skip one more row
Promote headers
Unpivot all columns except first column

You can do the same with each file and then combine processed files using Table.Combine
For example you can use this function for each file:
(fileName as text, sheetName as text) =>
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(fileName)){[Item = sheetName]}[Data],
    SkipUntilYear = Table.Skip(Source, each [Column2] <> "Year"),
    SkipOneMore = Table.Skip(SkipUntilYear),
    WithHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(SkipOneMore),
    RenameCol1 = Table.RenameColumns(WithHeaders, {"Column1", "Value"}),
    Unpivoted = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(RenameCol1, {"Value"}, "Year", "Amount")
in
    Unpivoted

This function has two parameters:

fileName - Excel-file full filename
sheetName - Sheet name within excel file

So if you apply this function to the first table you gave, you'll receive something like:

